# Not able to locate element in <a> tag having href as javascript

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the html code

I have tried these-
.//*[@id='contact_list-menu-contact_add']
//a[contains(@name,'add')]

But no success.

Comment: <a href="javascript:" id="contact_list-menu-contact_add" class="btn btn-contactadd primary"></a>

Comment: by any chance link is in an iframe?

Comment: may be i am not sure..IF you have any suggestion then let me know

Comment: if the link is in iframe, you have to switchto() the iframe before referring to the link.

Comment: Its not an Iframe, its only a button

Comment: pls try //a[@id='contact_list-menu-contact_add']  if this is not working, you may have add more html to the question for us to help you out.

Comment: hey man the link is in iframe.you are correct. How to switch to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find `<a>` tag mentioned in your comment,you do not need to write   `//a[contains(@name,'add')]`   after your xpath mentioned above.
The below mentioned xpath will work

```
//*[@id='contact_list-menu-contact_add']
```

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: //*[@id='contact_list-menu-contact_add'] this xpath is not working

Answer (score 0):

Switch to frame and click on the link:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  
driver.switchTo().frame("FRAME NAME");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='contact_list-menu-contact_add']")).click();
```

Comment: I am able to switch to frame buth this xapth expression //a[@id='contact_list-menu-contact_add'] not working

Comment: hmm, pls post the more html code. question is not really helpful to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a cssSelector.
I use [Selenide](http://selenide.org/) a good wrapper for Selenium. I would then search for your html example like this:

$(By.cssSelector("a[id='contact_list-menu-contact_add'][class*='add']"))